# How to update an AngularJS table cell value from database without refresh

Tags: angularjs, datatable

I have an application which displays a table (xeditable) by retrieving data from a mySQL database.

The database table which displays the content constantly changes in the background and I am trying to figure out how I can reflect those changes in the UI without refreshing the page or the entire table each time a change was made in the database.

Basically, I would like to "push" the changes to the view and a change has been detected in the database.

I understand that is not available with PHP/MySQL so I guess there must be a way around it by using either a 3rd party library or even a mid tier nodeJS...

I read on google's firebase (with ReactJS) how this can be achieved OTB and thought it may be possible to do without rewriting my entire app.

Any thoughts?

snippets of my current codebase:

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap','countTo','xeditable']);

app.filter('startFrom', function() {
    return function(input, start) {
        if(input) {
            start = +start; //parse to int
            return input.slice(start);
        }
        return [];
    }
});

app.filter('abs', function () {
  return function(val) {
    return Math.abs(val);
  }
});

app.run(function(editableOptions) {
  editableOptions.theme = 'bs3'; // bootstrap3 theme. Can be also 'bs2', 'default'
});

app.config(['$compileProvider', function($compileProvider) {
  $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|http?|file|data):/);
}]);



app.controller('customersCrtl', function ($scope, $http, $timeout, $interval, $window) {
    var init =  function loadItems(){
    $scope.$emit('LOAD');
    $scope.progressBar = { progress : 0 };
    $http.get('ajax/getItems.php').success(function(data){
        $scope.list = data;
        $scope.updateID = data.updateID;
        $scope.currentPage = 1; //current page
        $scope.entryLimit = 50; //max no of items to display in a page
        $scope.filteredItems = $scope.list.length; //Initially for no filter
        $scope.totalItems = $scope.list.length;
        $scope.priceInfo = {
          min: 0,
          max: 100000
        }
        $scope.$emit('UNLOAD');

        var array = $scope.list;
        var flags = [], output = [], l = array.length, i;
        for(i=0; i<l; i++) {
            if( flags[array[i].category]) continue;
            flags[array[i].category] = true;
            output.push(array[i].category);
        }

        var array_manufact = $scope.list;
        var flags = [], output_manufact = [], l = array_manufact.length, i;
        for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
            if( flags[array_manufact[i].manufacturer]) continue;
            flags[array_manufact[i].manufacturer] = true;
            output_manufact.push(array_manufact[i].manufacturer);
        }

        $scope.cats = output;
        $scope.manufact = output_manufact;

        //console.log($scope.cats);


    });

    (function progress(){
        if($scope.progressBar.progress < 100){
            $timeout(function(){
                $scope.progressBar.progress += 1;
                progress();
            },5);
        }
    })();
```

**index.html:**

```
<html>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="data in filtered = (list | filter:search | filter:{category:by_cat} | filter:{notes:by_notes} | filter:{Locked:by_search_locked} | filter:{external_link:by_external_link} | filter:{name:by_name} | filter:{cat2:by_cat2} | filter:{errorStatus:search`enter code here`_status} | filter:{error_status:search_status_opt} | orderBy : predicate :reverse) | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit" ng-class="{'success' : data.error_status=='--example1--', 'warning' : data.place_1_name!='my_stock', 'danger' : data.error_status == 'not loaded'}">
        <td ng-class='{red : data.Locked==1}'><center>{{data.ID}}</center></td>
        <td ng-class='{red : data.Locked==1}'><center>{{data.name}}</center></td>
        <td ng-class='{red : data.Locked==1}'>
        <center>
            cat: {{data.category}}
            <br/>
            cat2: {{data.category2}}
        </center></td>
        <td ng-class='{red : data.Locked==1}'><center>{{data.price}}</center></td>
        <td ng-class='{red : data.Locked==1}'><center>
            <div ng-if="data.notes.length > 0">
                <div ng-repeat="i in data.notes">
                    <b><font color="red">{{i}}</font></b>                           
                </div>
            </div>
            <div ng-if="data.notes.length==0">
                ---
            </div>
        </center>
        </td>
        <td ng-class='{red : data.Locked==1}'>
        <center>
          <div ng-if="data.minPrice !=''">
            <a href="#" editable-text="data.minPrice" onbeforesave="updateMinPrice(data.productID,$data)">
              <font class='green'>{{data.minPrice}}</font>                                                  
            </a>                                        
            <span ng-if="data.minPrice_last_changed!='---'">
                <br/>
                <br/>
                    LastChangedON:&nbsp;<font dir="ltr">{{data.minPrice_last_changed}}</font>
            </span>

          </div>
          <div ng-if="data.minPrice == '' ">
              <div editable-text="data.minPrice" onbeforesave="updateMinPrice(data.productID,$data)">
                <font class='orange'>click to add</font>
              </div>
          </div>
        </center></td>
</html>
```

Comment: Try implementing a polling technique.

Answer (score 0):

**Use the `$interval`<sup>[1](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval)</sup> service to poll your endpoint**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http, $interval) {

    $interval(function(){

       $http.get('/api/metrics').then(function(res){

           $scope.data = res.data;

       });

    },5000);
});
```

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CBiUBOdjQKqUTrH7SQOs?p=preview) simulating polling an endpoint with `$interval`

---

1. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval